# how to solve the equation $\dfrac{a}{x-a}+\dfrac{a}{y-a}$ is

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

Please provide the steps to solve the equation, the answer to this equation is zero
I am not sure how it is derived, Kindly help

if $x+y=29$ then the value of $\dfrac{a}{x-a}+\dfrac{a}{y-a}$ is

Comment: The answer depends on $xy$ and on $a$.

Comment: Can't solve 3 variables with 2 equations , plus you need to show what you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{a}{x-a}+\frac{a}{y-a}=
\frac{a(y-a+x-a)}{(x-a)(y-a)}=\frac{a(x+y-2a)}{(x-a)(y-a)}
$$
which is zero if and only if either $a=0$ or $x+y=2a$.

So I guess you read wrongly your assignment when reporting it as $x+y=29$: look closely and you'll see it has $x+y=2a$.

Comment: I looked at the question again, it is given as x + y = 29 but looking at the equation you have derived and possible value a=0  or x+y=2a i believe the question itself wrong, this question was asked in one of the competitive exam. Thanks for the derivation

Comment: @VinuKumar Pesky misprints! `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

I have got $$a\left(\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{29-x-a}\right)=a\left(\frac{29-x-a+x-a}{(x-a)(29-x-a)}\right)=\frac{a(29-2a)}{(x-a)(29-x-a)}$$
If you meantg that $$x+y=a$$ is given then we get $$\frac{a^2}{x(x-a)}$$

Comment: I think the OP meant that $x+y=2a$

Comment: I can not see and hear what he meant!

Comment: "the answer to this equation is zero I am not sure how it is derived" - OP